# How to use Zend\Db in Zend Framework 2 in a real world project? A quest about foreign keys and relationships

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-db

I've completed the tutorial of Zend 2 and feel a bit disappointed by the Zend\Db component. Indeed, it's not able to handle foreign keys (as a built in).

How to approach this problem for a real world project (at lease ten different tables and relationships)?

Should I consider to try more or less to rewrite the findDependentRowset or findParentRow of Zend_Db (ZF1)? Am I wrong if I think this is impossible because it would be breaking the dogma of the PHP object ignorant of the outside world sold with the Data Mapper pattern.

Should I always consider that the code using foreign keys/relationship have nothing to do in the objects representing entities? This could end up into a beautiful spaghetti code.

Should I drop Zend\Db for Doctrine or Propel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an opinionated question and therefore will be closed pretty soon. Ultimately `Doctrine2` (or `Propel`) just do the same thing, that you could do manually with `Zend\Db` and `HydrationStrategies`, too.

The thing is, `Zend\Db` has everything built in to create your own `Doctrine2`. You can do exactly the same kind of things, but `Zend\Db` is not to be seen as a full fledged [DBAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_abstraction_layer). The `Zend\Db` Component is meant to be handling Database-Queries. Furthermore a couple of things like `TableGateway` are given that one can use.

However if you expect for `Zend\Db` to BE a DBAL, then you're simply mistaken. `Zend\Db` has been lightened up from all the DBAL stuff, because there are better solutions out there. The two you've mentioned would come to mind at first. Even in ZF1, the `Zend_Db`-Components have never been able to match what a real DBAL could do and therefore the decision has been made during the design of ZF2 to light up the `Zend\Db`-Component. Now it's failry useful for easy things and you can use `HydrationStrategies` to do "ForeingKeyToObject"-Mappings, too, but it requires a bit of work. If you want an easier solution my vote would go for the [**DoctrineModule**](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule) and [**DoctrineORMModule**](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule)

Comment: That's a pretty detailed answer that helped my understanding, thanks!